# how to suppress python printing code using rpy2 for summary of models

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using rpy2 for running ivreg. However, whenever I try to print the summary of the model it prints the entire function and dataframe instead of just the results like R. Is there a way to have R like print. Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 
# R2pi package
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
# R imports (Assuming AER and ivpack are installed in R)
base = importr("base")
aer = importr("AER")
# Automatic conversion btw R Vectors and Python objects
numpy2ri.activate()
pandas2ri.activate()


def ivreg(*argv, **kwargs):
    model = aer.ivreg(*argv, **kwargs)
    return model

n = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.multivariate_normal(
                            mean=[0] * 5,
                            cov=np.ones((5,5)) + np.eye(5),
                            size=n),
                  columns =["Y", "X1", "X2", "Z1", "Z2"])
clusterid = np.tile([1,2,3,4,5], (n//5, ))
df['X3'] = np.random.uniform(1,4,n).round(0).astype(int)

# Example regression
model = ivreg(formula="Y ~ . ", data=df)
print(base.summary(model))
```

Answer (score 0):

This because your object is passed "inline" to the function call, that is it has no associated symbol name in R. In the snippet below `df` is just a data structure.

```
model = ivreg(formula="Y ~ . ", data=df)
print(base.summary(model))
```

You could assign columns in `df` to symbols in R's globalenv, as shown in the introduction:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/introduction.html#linear-models